# 301 redirection from www to subdomain and SEO

Tags: seo

I will soon launch a website that tends to be a part of a sites collection. I want to use 1 subdomain per site :

- site1.mydomain.com
- site2.mydomain.com
- site3.mydomain.com
- ...

For now, I have no time to write content for a www site (public presentation of my company). And I have only 1 site (site1.mydomain.com). I want to index site1 on its subdomain, and make a 301 redirection from www to site1 as long as site1 is alone on mydomain.com.

Is it bad for Google referencing engines ? If I put a canonical link in my site1 index page header such as `<link rel="canonical" href="http://site1.mydomain.com" />` in my header, is it ok for Google bots ?

Comment: any info about the closing vote ? I've found many related questions about 301 and canonical but nothing for my specific case : redirecting www as long as only 1 subdomain is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will there be *anything* on www? If not, then I'd suggest using a 301 redirect - unless you are planning on doing something quite soon. If you are having a site there (i.e. contact details, about page, etc) then I wouldn't use a canonical link on them, as you still want those indexing in their own right. But link to site1 from www still, of course.

If site1 is completely different to www then it doesn't make a lot of sense to have canonical links. If you're purely trying to get the authority passed through then 301 is probably best too, though might be possible depending on your content. We mainly use canonical to get rid of duplication problems, or when we have, for instance, a video page that shows a video and a little information, but we would rather have the main video index as the authoritative URL.

My best piece of advice is to use the redirects and canonical tags how they're supposed to be (for that you can read the tech specs - boring, but necessary!), and check out [Matt Cutts' take](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/rel-canonical-html-head/) on such things first.

Comment: So maybe I'm confusing from the beginning. Do I have to fear duplication content detection with a simple 301 redirection, and only one instance of my site1, with a DNS redirection from www to site1 ? And do I need a canonical link ?

Comment: No, if you had a 301 from www to site1, you would never see www, nor would Google. If you have duplicate content on www but don't want to redirect, then yes, a canonical link should be placed on www. If there is no duplicate content, and you want www to still be viewable, you should have no 301 redirecto *or* canonical link, and just link to site1 from www.

Comment: OK, that's clear now ! Thanks for your explanation !